# How to automatically sort random numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've got 2 columns in a spreadsheet.

Col. A contains a formula that generates a random number:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,100)
```

Col. B calculates the rank of the random number in A using

```
=RANK.AVG(A2,A$2:A$274).
```

I would like to sort Col. B but I can't because the random numbers recalculate ever time I hit the SORT button.

Is there any way to make a column of random numbers that will self sort?

Comment: You can turn auto-recalculate off (it's on the formulas ribbon) and the use the F9 key when you do want to recalculate.

Comment: Do they need to keep being randomized? Why not populate them, then copy the values?

Answer (score 3):

Try some variation of this:

```
A    B         C
1    =rand()    =large($b$1:$b$10,a1)
2    =rand()    =large($b$1:$b$10,a2)
3    =rand()    =large($b$1:$b$10,a3)
4    =rand()    =large($b$1:$b$10,a4)
5    =rand()    =large($b$1:$b$10,a5)
6    =rand()    =large($b$1:$b$10,a6)
7    =rand()    =large($b$1:$b$10,a7)
8    =rand()    =large($b$1:$b$10,a8)
9    =rand()    =large($b$1:$b$10,a9)
10   =rand()    =large($b$1:$b$10,a10)
```

I don't totally understand the order of calcs and recalcs in excel, but this seems to work once you have recalculated at least once  (Column C may not be ordered when you first paste in, but after a recalc it will).

Máté Juhász points out that  you could also replace `=large($b$1:$b$10,a1)` with `=large($b$1:$b$10,row() )`, which would cut the need for column A entirely. 
 In this examples, I have two header rows, so I adjust `row()` by 2.

```
A         B
Random Number Tables
Unsorted    Sorted 
=rand()    =large($a$2:$a$12,row()-2)
=rand()    =large($a$2:$a$12,row()-2)
=rand()    =large($a$2:$a$12,row()-2)
=rand()    =large($a$2:$a$12,row()-2)
=rand()    =large($a$2:$a$12,row()-2)
=rand()    =large($a$2:$a$12,row()-2)
=rand()    =large($a$2:$a$12,row()-2)
=rand()    =large($a$2:$a$12,row()-2)
=rand()    =large($a$2:$a$12,row()-2)
=rand()    =large($a$3:$a$12,row()-2)
```

Comment: Good approach. Instead of addition of a new column (A), you can also use `Row()`